# How write query for firestore when both 'OR' and 'AND' logic has to be used simultaneously?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to fetch chat data between two individuals from firestore database. let's say the two individuals are `Chris` and `Sam`.

I am trying to fetch data which holds the below condition:

`(to =='Chris' AND from == 'Sam') OR (to == 'Sam' AND from == 'Chris')`

Please guide me on how I can use both OR and AND logic in my firestore query.

Answer (score 1):

Firestore doesn't support OR queries that way. You'll have to run 2 different queries in Firestore:

```
const colRef = collection(db, "chats");

// Query for (to =='Chris' AND from == 'Sam')
const q1 = query(colRef, where("to", "==", "Chris"), where("from", "==", "Sam"))

// Query for (to == 'Sam' AND from == 'Chris')
const q2 = query(colRef, where("to", "==", "Sam"), where("from", "==", "Chris"))
```

A workaround would be to store a key with value `ChrisSam` (or `SamChris`) and use the `in` operator like this:

```
const q3 = query(colRef, where("field", "in", ["ChrisSam", "SamChris"]))
```

However, this will require you to have unique user names across the applications (or use the User IDs instead). Also make sure the security rules only allow these 2 to query these documents.

Comment: One more thing to mention, the `in` operator allows you to combine up to [10 equality clauses](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#in_not-in_and_array-contains-any).

Comment: @AlexMamo yes the approach in my answer should require max 2 values only. Just the usernames of those 2 users. Ideally the user IDs.